# Extract fully quallified classname out of a java.lang.reflect.Method-object with or without Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a method that should extract the fully qualified class name out of a **java.lang.reflect.Method**-object. As i could not find any convenience method to get the classname of a Method-object, i'm trying to extract it with the following Regex-expression:

```
([A-Za-z.]*)[\(]
```

(maybe there's also a way without a Regex?).

```
public String getFullClassName(Method method) {
  // Example methodname:
  // public void com.test.user.impl.UserServiceImpl.deleteUser(java.lang.Long) throws com.test.user.api.exception.UserServiceException
  String methodName = method.toString();
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z.]*)[\\(]");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(methodName);
  String result = "";
  while (m.find()) {
      result = m.group();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Unfortunately, the Regex i built does not work correctly, as it gives me two result groups, but it should only give me one group. When i call the method with the Method

```
public void com.test.user.impl.UserServiceImpl.deleteUser(java.lang.Long) throws com.test.user.api.exception.UserServiceException
```

,i get two matching groups:

```
Group(0) = com.test.user.impl.UserServiceImpl.deleteUser(
Group(1) = com.testuser.impl.UserServiceImpl.deleteUser
```

so the method returns the first group "*com.test.user.impl.UserServiceImpl.deleteUser(*", but it should be "*com.test.user.impl.UserServiceImpl.deleteUser*". I don't want to choose the group manually, but i want a Regex that should already give me one matching group. Whats wrong with my Regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String methodName = method.getDeclaringClass().getName()
```

if you insist to use regex, here is the fix:

```
while (m.find()) {
    result = m.group(1);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

`group()` or `group(0)` ALWAYS return the whole matched string. You need `group(n)` where `n > 0` to get the value inside bracket.

However, I'd suggest that you are not using regex for this case.

Comment: Damn... i swear i also tried that without success ;) But know it works. Anyway, if anyone also has a fix for my regex it would be fine, just to know how i would write a matching regex when there would be no convenience method

Comment: Thanks. Of course i'm not using the Regex now. But there must be a better regex which only gives me one group (without the opening brace)?

Comment: You can try Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z.]*)"), but it will also give java.lang.Long and com.test.user.api.exception.UserServiceException